# jQuery focusout event repeating itself issue

Tags: jquery, focus, jquery-events

This thing works, but each time I am clicking the element I want to get, it's "count" the clicks and then print log comments for the same number of total clicks.

For example, if I click the element 3 times in a row (and then clicking outside to trigger the `focusout`), it prints 3 log comments, if I then click 2 more times (and outside again) it prints 5 `log` comments.

And I want to get only one `log` comment each time when I am clicking outside the element.

Help anyone?

```
 $("#main-wrapper").click(function (e) {
    var contenteditable = $(e.target).attr('contenteditable');
    if (contenteditable == 'true') {
        $(e.target).focusout(function() {
            var content = $(this).html();
            console.log("get: " + content);
        });
    };          
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try unbinding the event.

```
$("#main-wrapper").click(function (e) {
var contenteditable = $(e.target).attr('contenteditable');
if (contenteditable == 'true') {
    $(e.target).unbind('focusout').focusout(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();
        console.log("get: " + content);
    });
};          
});
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this will also unbind the `click` handler, so this would only work for the first click. You should be able to do `unbind('focusout')` though.

Answer (score 1):

You are attaching a new `focusout` event handler each time you handle a `click`. These event handlers are not *replaced*, but *added*, and each event handler is executed when the event is triggered. That's why you get the same number of logged messages as previous clicks.

You should be able to specify the `focusout` handler just once, but how you want it to be triggered is of course depending on what you want to accomplish.

```
$("#main-wrapper").focusout(function (e) {
  var contenteditable = $(e.target).attr('contenteditable');
  if (contenteditable == 'true') {
    var content = $(this).html();
    console.log("get: " + content);
  }          
});
```